# Combine two excel files into ONE worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, csv, merge

I want to merge two CSV files into ONE Worksheet Either to overwrite one of them or create a new CSV file.
The important thing is that i want this process to be done AUTOMATICALLY (in some scheduled time).
Any help?!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could parse both csv files into two list objects and write them to one other unique csv file. Maybe you can start with this. If the char for the csv is different from ',' just replace it  in the code below.

```
public List<string[]> parseCSV(string path)
{
         List<string[]> parsedData = new List<string[]>();

         using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path))
         {
                  string line;
                  string[] row;

                  while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                  {

                           row = line.Split(',');
                           parsedData.Add(row);
                  }
         }
         return parsedData;
}
```